# retrieve docs from monogdb collection with field condition

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to query a mongodb collection and retrieve certain documents based on a field value but also only retrieve a single field per record. I tried the following but no getting the solution I want:

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = 
    database.getCollection("client_data"); 
        //Document document = collection
        //            .find(new BasicDBObject("sampleUser", "myDb"))
        //.projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("address"), 
        //Projections.excludeId())).first();
        

        BasicDBObject aQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        aQuery.put("clientId",567);
        FindIterable<Document> iterDoc = collection.find(aQuery);
```

The following retrieves all documents for clientid =  567, but I only want to show the address field.
The commented out code was also what I tried but not sure how to combine that with the query.

EDIT:

I am now able to iterate through all the results but would like to parse each document; I tried parsing the document into my class object but it immediately gives an error:

```
Unrecognized field "_id" (class 
         model.Client), not marked as ignorable
```

But _id is the very first field in the document:

```
   Document{{_id=6216a7f64cedfd00011c35a5,
```

So I tried something else rather using the first document but then I don't know how to get the next document:

```
     while(cursor.hasNext()) {               
                   // System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
                    Client client = new Client();
                  try {
                      
                      JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser(cursor.next().toJson());
                      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                      ObjectNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
                      String customerInfo = fi.first().toJson();
                      JsonNode jobj = mapper.readTree(customerInfo);
                      
                     // this gives the error// client = mapper.readValue(jsonParser,Client.class);
                      
client.setId(jobj.path("_id").path("$oid").asText());
```

Please advise.

Comment: Can you add a sample document ? What is not working with your current code ?  
Try `FindIterable<Document> iterDoc = collection.find(Filters.eq("clientId", 567)).projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("add‌​ress"), Projections.excludeId()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to:

> retrieves all documents for clientid = 567, but I only want to show the address field

You would execute the following:

```
collection
    .find(Filters.eq("clientId", 567))
    .projection(Projections.fields(
        Projections.include("address"),  
        Projections.excludeId())
    ).first()
```

Breaking it down:

- `.find(Filters.eq("clientId", 567))`: apply the predicate 'where clientId = 567'
- `.projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("address"), Projections.excludeId()))`: let the response include the `address` field and exclude the `_id` field

Comment: Thank you; this was helpful and worked. I have a related question now that I can retrieve the documents.